# Use a ListView.builder and wrap widgets dynamically

Tags: flutter, listview, word-wrap

I try to solve the following problem: I want to have a dynamically generated set of cards widgets which should be layed out horizontal and wrap the line when the card is getting too big:
[image]

I was thinking of a ListView.builder but this can either go horizontal or vertical. More, a gridview seems also not the best option as I have no fixed columns or rows. Is there any way in doing so or exists there maybe a widget I am not aware of currently?

Comment: What about [`Wrap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)?

Comment: Oh really why I have not found this before. Thanks I will have look at this widget :)